# Table name specified twice, both as a target for update and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am receiving an expected error from my code whenever I attempt to update my table using a select statement although I am trying different workarounds with no hopes to success. Any help with my issue would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

```
UPDATE `table`
SET Slope = CASE

when (SELECT ((SELECT (SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn desc limit 1) - (SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn ASC limit 1) FROM DUAL)) as x) > 0 THEN 'Uptrend' 

when (SELECT ((SELECT (SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn desc limit 1) - (SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn ASC limit 1) FROM DUAL)) AS x) < 0 THEN 'Downtrend' 

when (SELECT ((SELECT (SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn desc limit 1) - (SELECT dialcount FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn ASC limit 1) FROM DUAL)) AS x) = 0 THEN 'Notrend' 

else 'unknown' END

UPDATE `table`
SET Slope = CASE
when ((SELECT (SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn desc limit 1) - (SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn ASC limit 1) FROM DUAL)) > 0 THEN 'Uptrend' 
when ((SELECT (SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn desc limit 1) - (SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn ASC limit 1) FROM DUAL)) < 0 THEN 'Downtrend' 
when ((SELECT (SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn desc limit 1) - (SELECT dialcount FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn ASC limit 1) FROM DUAL)) = 0 THEN 'Notrend' 

else 'unknown' END
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I'm not quite sure the point of this update query. Are you really wanting to update every the `slope` of every row in the table to the same value based on the least and most recent values in the entire table?

Comment: I am getting #1093 error: table name specified twice both as a target for update and as a separate source

Comment: Uueerdo i started off with trying to get the slope value from my table but it all failed, so i am trying at least to define the kind of it until I migrate my code to another platform like python or R which are more rich with libraries for analytics. If you know a workable formula for getting the slope using only two columns (which are a date and a number) I will be highly appreciated.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
update table set Slope = case 
when ((SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn desc limit 1) - (SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn ASC limit 1))>0 then 'Uptrend'
when ((SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn desc limit 1) - (SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn ASC limit 1))<0 then 'Downtrend'
when ((SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn desc limit 1) - (SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn ASC limit 1))=0 then 'Notrend'
else 'unknown' end
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer. I tried this method as well but it gives a new kind of an error which says that the table doesn't even exists and I found this very weird.

Comment: Replace table with your table name

Comment: It's not like that. Definitely I was doing so. It's mysql that doesn't support updating against a subquery that's why it needed some kind of rephrasing and I managed to write it the way it would work! I shared it here-under. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working as following:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET Slope = CASE
when ((SELECT(SELECT (SELECT intcolumn FROM (SELECT intcolumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn desc limit 1) as lastdc) - (SELECT intcolumn FROM (SELECT intcolumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn ASC limit 1) as firstdc) FROM DUAL) as dff)) > 0 THEN 'Uptrend' 
when ((SELECT(SELECT (SELECT intcolumn FROM (SELECT intcolumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn desc limit 1) as lastdc) - (SELECT intcolumn FROM (SELECT intcolumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn ASC limit 1) as firstdc) FROM DUAL) as dff)) < 0 THEN 'Downtrend' 
when ((SELECT(SELECT (SELECT intcolumn FROM (SELECT intcolumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn desc limit 1) as lastdc) - (SELECT intcolumn FROM (SELECT intcolumn FROM `table` ORDER by DateColumn ASC limit 1) as firstdc) FROM DUAL) as dff)) = 0 THEN 'Notrend' 
else 'unknown' END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a query to calculate the slope, something like this should work:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN lastInt > firstInt THEN 'Uptrend'
    WHEN lastInt > firstInt THEN 'Downtrend'
    WHEN lastInt > firstInt THEN 'Notrend'
    END AS `slope`
FROM (
    SELECT (SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER BY DateColumn DESC LIMIT 1) AS lastInt
        , (SELECT IntColumn FROM `table` ORDER BYDateColumn ASC LIMIT 1) AS firstInt
    ) AS boundInts
;
```